# Javascript + JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a controller and a JSP File.

In my controller I have :

```
request.setAttribute("AListOfClient", AListOfClient );// AListOfObject is a List
```

In my jsp File :

```
<input type="hidden" id="AListOfClient" name="AListOfClient" value="${AListOfClient}" />
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var item = ${(AListeOfClient[0]).name}; // no problem with this
</script>
```

But I want to do a for  :

```
for (i=0; i < ${length}; i++) {
var item = ${(AListeOfClient[i]).name}; // ERROR
var item = ${(AListeOfClient[0]).name}; // No Problem
});
```

Someone can help me??

For the solution :

```
var jsAListOfClient= [
<c:forEach items="${AListOfClient}" var="client">
"${client.name}",
</c:forEach>
                    ];
```

Eclipse said that "Syntax error on token ""${client.name}"", delete this token"

If I remplace "${client.name}" by " ", Eclipse says the same thing...

Comment: what is the value of `i` when you are reaching your error?  your array doesn't seem to be as big as you think

Comment: It is not a OutOfBoundsException. It doesn't reconize the parameter 'i'...

Comment: You are horribly confusing server- and client-side code. And please, consider calling "a list of client" something like... "clients".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN your javascript do this, simply create js array and poplutae with jstl.

```
var jsAListOfClient= [
        <c:forEach items="${AListOfClient}" var="client">
        "${client.name}",
        </c:forEach>
    ];
```

then you cna reference your jsList how you want. But I agree with others just refactor and use jstl.

Comment: Why did it says : Syntax error on token ""${client.name}"", delete this token in Eclipse....

Comment: @aeasse becuase your client class has no method getName()

Comment: client have the method getName(). Even if i put this, it says the same thing :var jsAListOfClient= [
        <c:forEach items="${AListOfClient}" var="client">
        "blabla",
        </c:forEach>
    ];

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. I fyou have latered the code an dreceive a different error message please update your question, Or post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store the list as a hidden variable in jsp file. Better you iterate that list using JSTL and create hidden variables.

Why do you want to store the list on jsp page?

Anyways, here is the alternate approach:

Iterate the list using JSTL, create the hidden variables, give them proper ids. And in javascript, iterate over these hidden variables and you will get the required values. Javascript is client side whilst the list you are attaching in request object is server side, hence it can't be accessed.

Comment: Because i'm using a JBoss Server